# What subvariety corresponds to the preimage of an ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a morphism of complex affine varieties. Denote the coordinate rings of $X$ and $Y$ by $\mathbb{C}[X]$ and $\mathbb{C}[Y]$ respectively. Then $f$ corresponds to a ring homomorphism $f^* : \mathbb{C}[Y] \to \mathbb{C}[X]$. It is an easy exercise to show that for every ideal $I \lhd \mathbb{C}[X]$, the preimage $J := (f^*)^{-1}(I)$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{C}[Y]$.

**Question.** *If an ideal $I \lhd \mathbb{C}[X]$ corresponds to a subvariety $Z \subset X$, then what subvariety of $Y$ does the preimage $J = (f^*)^{-1}(I)$ correspond to?*

The obvious guess is that it corresponds to the image $f(Z) \subset Y$, but I've read in many places that the image is not necessarily a subvariety. Is it the closure $\overline{f(Z)}$? Or something else?

Comment: It is the scheme-theoretic image of Z.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it the closure $\overline{f(Z)}$?

Yes indeed. Remember that we think of elements $g \in \mathbb C[Y]$ as functions $g: Y \to \mathbb C$. The map $f^*$ is then just composition $f^*g = g \circ f: X \to Y \to \mathbb C$. Now such a function $g$ vanishes on $f(X)$ if and only if $f^*g$ vanishes on $X$, i.e. $f^*g \in \sqrt{I}$. But this is equivalent to $g \in \sqrt{J}$.

---

Let me end this with an example, whose image is neither open nor closed. Take $$f:\mathbb C^2 \to \mathbb C^2, (x,y) \mapsto (x, xy).$$ Its image is
$$f(\mathbb C^2) = \{\, (x,y) \in \mathbb C^2 : x \neq 0 \,\} \cup \{(0,0)\}$$